# Insert html_tag class attribute - wrong formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

We have created a custom field error message for fields for a form. When an error is caught, we display a message by the field explaining to the user that the field can't be blank. The text is displayed when a `text-danger is-invalid` class' are present.

My problem lies within the else of the following code:

**Code**

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|

  case html_tag
    ...
  when /<label/
    class_attr_index = html_tag.index 'class="'
    if class_attr_index
      ...
    else 
      %(#{ html_tag.insert html_tag.index('>'), ' class="text-danger is-invalid"' }
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          #{ /\[(.*)\]/.match(instance.send(:tag_name))[1] }
          #{ instance.error_message[0] }
        </div>
      ).html_safe
    end
  else
    html_tag
  end
end
```

The basic way this works is by capturing the html_tag, for example:
`<label>Name</label>`

We check if the html_tag contains the 'class=' attribute, which in our case it does not, then insert the class attribute with the desired classes.

**Desired outcome:**

`<label class="text-danger is-invalid">Name</label>`

**Actual outcome:**

`<label class=""text-danger" is-invalid&quot;>Name</label>`

Does anyone know why it is setting the classes in a weird way and what the `&quot;` is?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I probably don't understand the complexities and/or subtleties of what you're doing. But, that looks like a whole lot of really heavy lifting to insert a class value.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/telwell/db42a4dafbe9cc3b7988debe358c88ad check this gist, may give you some direction to handle your issue.